# awk scripts in windows with MinGW

Tags: batch-file, awk, cygwin, mingw

We have an old legacy system that uses awk script for the deploy. I want to make minimum changes in it. We used to work with Cygwin and recently we've replaced it to MinGW.

Long story short, the script uses the system() command in order to run a cmd batch file like this:

```
system("cmd /c addVersion.bat " f ".map " f "." major "." minor ".map " f)
```

(I know complex and not ideal, but again I want minimum changes in that thing)

With Cygwin this command used to run the addVersion.bat and print the output to the console.  with MinGW it only opens a new instance of CMD and does nothing.

we are working on windows10 with MinGW and Msys.
I looked a lot on the internet and found nothing. (guess cause I didn't know the right keywords in order to find a relevant solution)

if anyone has any idea or suggestion please let me know.

Comment: have you tested that `system()` works with any other command? If so, have to tested that `system("cmd /c")` can run any other command? Have you tried replacing all variable values(`f`,`map`,`major`,`minor`) with hard coded values? Are  you using MinGW/Msys or the "newer" MSYS2 variant. My impression (from an occasional glance at support forums), is that MSYS2/Mingw(32/64) are newer and better supported. In either case, post/search to the correct support forums and you might find something (It sounds like you may have done that already). Well, Out of ideas ;-) .  Good luck!

Comment: Untested, as I don't have an Msys environment. But if `system()` is misbehaving, you might try `getline` as an alternative. Try replacing that line with `cmd = "cmd /c addVersion.bat " f ".map " f "." major "." minor ".map " f` and then `while (cmd | getline) { print }; close(cmd)`. This will consume `$0` and `NF` and so forth, but you can store `$0` to a var then restore it after if needed. Or if addVersion.bat doesn't produce any useful output, just `getline throwawayvar cmd` instead of the `while` loop. Or port addVersion.bat's work load into native awk and forego the polyglot handoff.

Comment: @shellter thanks for the suggestions. Yes System works with other commands and it works with "cmd /c" as well just not as expected. I tried replacing variables and it didnt change anything. I thought as well as changing to msys2 but sadly it is not possible because of some other issues. Thanks alot anyway :)

Comment: @rojo thanks alot! Thats a really good idea to use getline. I need the output of &amp;quot;addVersion.bat&amp;quot; But storing $0 to a var should solve the problem. Again thanks alot, sadly ill be able to check that only sunday morning